# Percent Similar Texts and Tolerance Level

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

**Case scenario:**

Imagine a key-value object (dictionary), that contains the following data:

```
{ 
   'www.example.com/':2,
   'www.example.com/happy/':4
}
```

I receive a value from a source that contains the following data:

```
{
    'www.example.com//':4
}
```

It's obvious that www.example.com// is very very similar to www.example.com/. Instead of creating a new entry in my dictionary, I would like the code to see the closest key in my dictionary in terms of text similarity, and then sum up the numbers. Therefore, the final state of the dictionary would look like this:

```
{ 
   'www.example.com/':6,
   'www.example.com/happy/':4
}
```

The summing part is easy and bouncing against tolerance is easy, but the challenging part is what's the best algorithm to utilize as the dictionary grows?

i.e. Do I have to loop through the dictionary everytime and check the key (something like this:

```
for key in dictionary:
    if tolerance > diff(key,collected_data):
        dictionary[key] += collected_data[value]
        break
```

)

But the example above doesn't stop until it finds the best value, which isn't ideal.

Comment: This is really more of a natural language processing problem. There are many approaches to it, but a classical one breaking down the strings into words-like parts and utilizing something such as [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to determine the degree of similarity. [NTLK](http://www.nltk.org/) can be useful in the actual implementation.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra NTLK has great potential, thank you for sharing it! I need to see if there are any practical applications in the realm of URLs/Hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want some sort of locality sensitive hashing (LSH), I've never tried it before, but you could try something like http://nearpy.io/